# How do I get a Connection to h2 database in swing

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

I wrote this code but it doesn't work.

It throws an error that says that this is not suitable Driver.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class ConnectionUtil {

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.h2.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("org.h2:database/javadb", "root", "");
            return con;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your URL is wrong. http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#connecting_using_jdbc

Comment: If my Url is wrong,Plz give me Suggestion  about url?

Answer (score 0):

I used this URL for a connection to my DB "jdbc:h2:file:./database/mydatabase"